# Transit Visa requirement for San Francisco to Cape Town via London

Tags: visas, uk, london, south-african-citizens

Do I need a visa for a 7 hour layover as I have South Africian passport on route from SF to London to Cape Town

Comment: Related Question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21171/sa-nationals-in-transit-from-canada-to-joburg-through-lhr-landside-visa-requi?rq=1

Comment: Additional Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10546/do-turkish-citizens-need-a-visa-to-come-to-the-uk-for-one-day, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/18-hr-layover-in-london-should-i-get-a-transit-visa-to-explore-london-is-s?rq=1

Comment: Are you going to leave the airport?